# Arabic characters right aligned and center aligned with html2canvas

Tags: html, css, html2canvas

well im saving a div with html2canvas containing arabic text.
the issue is if i right aligned the arabic text it saves the arabic text perfectly but if the arabic text is center aligned it shows on the page properly but when it saves the image , on image arabic character are shown separately.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h1uLrpym/5/)

Image Below:

[image]

```
<div id="canvasSaveder">
<input id="charA" type="text" name="aname" style="text-align: center;"
value="انا احبک"
class="arx resizeME nameA">
</div>

    <button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary top">
        Create Image</button>
    <div id="img" style="display:none;">
        <img src="" id="newimg" class="top" />
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#myButton").click(function() {
            html2canvas($("#canvasSaveder"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    console.log(imgsrc);
                    $("#newimg").attr('src', imgsrc);
                    $("#img").show();
                    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "save_printed_id.php",
                        data: {
                            imgBase64: dataURL
                        }
                    }).done(function(o) {
                        console.log('saved');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it the act of saving that creates the problem? It would seem more likely that the canvas is misrendered. Could you create a simple example whrich shows the problem which we could run to see for ourselves? In particular, what CSS is being used? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth here is jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/h1uLrpym/5/) for example to run